# Copy a Group Layer QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector

How would I copy a group layer in QGIS? I see that you can duplicate layers but copying a layer group is much quicker.

What am I missing, is there a standard way, plugin, or python code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save a group as Layer Definition File, but this feature is available only in the master version (which will be soon QGIS 2.8.0).

If you are using this version:

1. Right click on the Group and choose "Save as Layer Definition File"
2. From the Layer, menu choose "Add from Layer Definition File"
3. Repeat the step number 2 all the time you need.

Comment: How do I get QGIS 2.8? I only see 2.6 available on the qgis.org page.